# How do i filter and remove lines that don't contain the specifc word/s?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method for now:

```
private void WordsFilter(List<string> newText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newText.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
        {
            lineToPost = ScrollLabel._lines[i];
            if (!lineToPost.Contains(WordsList.words[x]))
            {
                newText.Remove(lineToPost);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

newText is List and WorldsList.words is string[]

I loop over the lines in newText and loop over the words and i want to check this way:

First line in newText to loop over all the words if none of any of the words exist in this line remove the current line and the next line after it.
For example in newText if line in index 0 is : Hello everyone
And line in index 1 is: created at 12/3/2002
Then remove index 0 and index 1

Index 2 is empty like a space empty line so do not remove it.

Then index 3 to loop over all the words if nonoe of the words exist in line in index 3 remove index 3 and index 4 .

And so on...

How can i do it ?

Comment: Please delete all that and use proper LINQ. C# is not java

Answer (score 0):

[Here a working example](http://dotnetfiddle.net/IDAMz7). I try to didnt change the logic of your code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>() {"truc", "I love toto", "next", "chocolate", "tata tata", "", "something"};
        WordsFilter(list);
    }

    private static void WordsFilter(List<string> newText)
    {
        string[] WordsList = new string[] { "toto", "tata" };

        for (int i = 0; i < newText.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.Length; x++)
            {
                if (newText[i].Contains(WordsList[x]))
                {
                    newText.RemoveAt(i);
                    if (i + 1 < newText.Count)
                        newText.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // print
        foreach(var item in newText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You should check how works [`foreach` loop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) and [LINQ](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq).